# If/else response based on query param in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have this code in my express app:

```
        ...
        res.status(200);
        if (download === true) {
          res.download("./src/data/file.txt");
          res.end()
        } else {
          res.json({ msg: msges.success });
        }
```

When query param **download=true** is sent with request, file is downloaded as expected but it has not data from that path, but data are just that **.json** from else statement. If else is removed, the file contain correct data.

Answer (score 0):

When queryParams are sent, They are treated as a **string**.

This is the reason which is failing your **if statement**.

So you should try: -

```
       if (download === 'true') {
          res.download("./src/data/file.txt");
          res.end()
        } else {
          res.json({ msg: msges.success });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Express `Query params` are strings. You compare a string with a boolean value via `===` operator, then it alway be false, this mean your code never come to `if` block.

Just compare a string with a string:

```
...
if (download === "true") { // string `"true"`
...
```

Comment: Thank you. I should be aware of that. It come from axios req where params are sends like object -> params : { download : true }, that probably confused me.